# Which F1 driver was overtaken after swerving towards his team at the pit wall?

Tags: formula-1

Which F1 driver swerved towards his team at the pit wall, causing him to be overtaken? Other things I remember:

- He lost the race and his job because of this.
- It may have been in a Renault.
- It may have been Jarno Trulli or Giancarlo Fisichella.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - could you please write any future posts using proper capitalisation? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be misremembering an incident that occurred with Jarno Trulli at the 2004 French Grand Prix, while he was driving for Renault. Trulli was 3rd on the final lap, but with only a few corners to go, he ran wide and allowed Rubens Barrichello to overtake him, losing out on a podium finish. Trulli wasn't sacked immediately after the incident, but it did sour his relationship with the team, and he was ultimately sacked with three races to go, having failed to score any points since the French GP.

You can see footage of the incident here:

Alternatively, you may be recalling an incident in an F3000 race at Monaco, in which Bjorn Wirdheim did exactly what you describe: he slowed down and swerved towards the pit wall to celebrate, thinking he'd already crossed the finish line, and Nicolas Kiesa overtook him and stole the win. Again, though, Wirdheim wasn't sacked, and actually went on to win the F3000 title that year.

You can see footage of *that* incident here: